Jenkins controller UI not properly loading
I have Jenkins running on windows server, and noticed this morning I couldn't get the host controller UI to properly load. The windows service is running, and I tried restarting it.
Checking the logs for Jenkins, noticed it is throwing an exception h.i.i.installuncaughtexceptionhandler#handlerexception:com4j.comexception:8007203a the server is not operational: the server is not operational: .\invoke.cpp:517. Then, there are a exceptions from hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDiretoryAuthenticationProvider.
Just before the exceptions, Jenkins was updating a number of plugins, but I can't tell if active directory was one them as it is not listed.
Does anyone know what is going on here?
